# How to express symbolically "C and B have at least one element in common"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is this correct? If it is, is there a better way to write it?

$C\cap B≠\{Ø\}$

Comment: It should be $C \cap B \neq\emptyset$ (empty set) instead of $C \cap B \neq \{\emptyset\}$ (a set containing one element which happens to be an empty set)

Comment: There are also other (worse?) ways to write it, e.g. $(\exists x)(x\in C\land x\in B)$

Comment: One more: $\mathcal{P}(C\cap B)\geq 1$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu But does not $\mathcal P$ denote the power set? I've never seen it used to mean the cardinality. I'd write it as $|C \cap B| \ge 1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy No, it is wrong.

Comment: @PrimeMover, you're correct. I've should use other designation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions

1. $B$ and $C$ have at least one element in common
2. There is at least one element that belongs to both $B$ and $C$
3. $B$ and $C$ are not disjoint
4. $B \cap C$ is non-empty
5. $B \cap C \ne \emptyset$
6. $\exists x$ such that $ x \in B \cap C$

They all say the same thing. Picking one is really just a matter of taste and style.